# JPA - How to check a conditional before in a ManyToOneRelationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 entities, `Car` and `Person`. One person can have multiple cars. So I have

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Table(name="Car")
public class Car {
  @Id
  private String id;

  private String name;
  
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
  private Person person;
}

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Table(name="Person")
public class Person {
  @Id
  private String id;

  private String name;
  
  private String address;
}
```

However, I only want to load cars for which the owner has an address set (so it's not null).

I have tried adding

```
@Where(clause = "address IS NOT NULL")
```

but to no help.

To translate it to SQL terms, I need the query to be
`SELECT * FROM car c JOIN person p ON c.person_id = p.id WHERE p.address IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a Query

```
select c from Car c where c.person.address is not null
```

The @Where annotation (btw. this is a Hibernate proprietary and not a JPA annotation) is used on collections to filter the content.